# how to create a email content using google direction response?

Tags: php, javascript, google-maps

i can get the directions from one place to another in my local gmap
i need to mail that direction data to any email id specified in a text box.

i found that gdirection.getDistence()[html], and gdirection.getDescriptionHtml() are embedded with html tags

is there any way to do my task?
are the above methods useful or what is the correct way to do this?

please help me on this

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can handle response using JavaScript to extract the information you need to email. Pls refer to [Google Maps API documentation](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/services.html#DirectionsRequests) for more info.